# Rails Functional Test Failing Due to Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have an accounts model that holds some basic account info (account name, website, etc).  I then have a user model that has the following in the app/models/user.rb

```
belongs_to :account
```

I also have the following in my routes.rb

```
map.resources :account, :has_many => [:users, :othermodel]
```

the problem I'm facing is that the following test is failing:

```
test "should create user" do
  assert_difference('User.count') do
    post :create, :user => { } #this is the line it's actually failing on
  end

  assert_redirected_to user_path(assigns(:user)) #it doesn't get here yet
end
```

The error it gives is "Can't find Account without ID" so I kind of understand WHY it's failing, because of the fact that it doesn't have the account object (or account_id as it were) to know under what account to create the user.  I have tried variations of the following but I am completely lost:

```
post :create, :user => { accounts(:one) } #I have the 'fixtures :accounts' syntax at the top of the test class

post :create, [accounts(:one), :user] => { }

post :create, :user => { accounts(:one), #other params for :user }
```

and like I said, just about every variation I could think of.  I can't find much documentation on doing this and this might be why people have moved to Factories for doing test data, but I want to understand things that come standard in Rails before moving onto other things.

Can anyone help me get this working?

### UPDATE:

I managed to get the test to fail in a different location, I had to ensure that the test could actually get to the create action (have some authlogic stuff in my app)

it now says

> undefined method 'users' for nil:Class

So now it's saying that it can't find a users collection on my @account object in the controller, basically because it still can't find the @account even though it doesn't actually fail to find the account in question.  So my `before_filter :find_account` works to the extent that it doesn't break, but it seem to not be finding the account.

I tried the `post :create, :id => @account.id, :user => { }` but to no avail.  Also tried `post :create, :account => accounts(:one), :user => { }` and `:user => { :account => accounts(:one) }`, again with the same result.

Comment: I think you want `post :create, :account_id => @account.id`

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the association backwards. If that's the case then `Account` model should `belong_to :user`, then `User` model should `has_one :account`.

Otherwise, since you're creating user which belongs to some account, you should pass account's `:id` in params:

```
post :create, :id => some_test_account.id, :user => {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical controller for the `belongs_to` side of a `has_many` association would have a create action like this:

```
def create
  @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
  @user = @account.users.build(params[:user])
  if @account.save
    # handle success
  else
    # handle failure
  end
end
```

If your controller doesn't look like this you not be handling the parameters correctly, thus the test failure.

You can also check your routes. You should see something like:

`POST   /accounts/:account_id/users(.:format) {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}`

That's another clue that Rails is setting `params[:account_id]` to the value for the requested account.

Comment: I have a before_filter :get_user_account in my users_controller that finds the account by id before doing any other stuff.  So all that is set up correctly.

Comment: Hmm. Have you looked in the test log?

Comment: test log didn't show anything out of the ordinary, is there a way to make it more verbose?